# How to display only the pop-up capture frame

Tags: org-mode, frames, org-capture

During (org-capture) invoked from any other app on OSX, Emacs displays the non-capture frame as well (behind the capture frame).  Is there a way to get Emacs display the capture window only when (org-capture) is invoked?  In other words, what is the way to separate the capture buffer frame from the main Emacs frame and display only the capture frame?  Thank you.
-jay

Answer (score 1):

I think `display-buffer-alist` is generally used to dictate this sort of thing, but it looks like the behavior is hard-coded in `org-capture-place-template`.

If I'm understanding you correctly-- making this modification to org-capture-place-template should yield your desired behavior in the created frame:

```
   (unless inhibit-wconf-store
     (org-capture-put :return-to-wconf (current-window-configuration)))
   (delete-other-windows)
-  (org-switch-to-buffer-other-window
-   (org-capture-get-indirect-buffer (org-capture-get :buffer) "CAPTURE"))
+  (org-no-popups
+   (switch-to-buffer
+    (org-capture-get-indirect-buffer (org-capture-get :buffer) "CAPTURE")))
   (widen)
   (outline-show-all)
   (goto-char (org-capture-get :pos))
```